# Command which will tell me the last time a directory or any of its sub directories have been modified?

Tags: linux, bash

We are trying to deprecate our old Linux home folder server. We still have a few people that are actively using it though.
Our plan is to change home folders that no one has used in the last six months to read only.
We have Mac and Windows clients accessing these shares over SMB.

So my question is:
Is there a command which will tell me the last time a directory or any of its sub directories have been modified?

Or

A list of parent directories that have been modified since a certain date?

This would tell me what users are still actively using their home folders.

Comment: This would be trivial to implement as a bash one-liner. What have you tried thus far on your own?

Comment: Stop the SMB shares, wait for who calls. :)

Comment: I've tried this but not to sure of the results. I'm not sure if I trust the results.

find . -type d -mtime -730 | xargs -r ls -l`code`

Comment: Why would you not trust the results?

Comment: Maybe this sounds dumb, but something about it didn't seem right haha. Judging from your comments i'm assuming this is the way to do it though.

Answer (score 3):

A problem you might run into is that modifying a file in a directory doesn't necessarily change the directory time stamp.  Here's an example:

```
paulgear@localhost:~/tmp$ echo test1 > test1
paulgear@localhost:~/tmp$ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 paulgear paulgear   18 Jan 15 09:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 paulgear paulgear 3976 Jan 15 09:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 paulgear paulgear    0 Jan 15 09:29 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 paulgear paulgear    6 Jan 15 09:29 test1
paulgear@localhost:~/tmp$ date
Wed Jan 15 09:30:07 EST 2014
paulgear@localhost:~/tmp$ echo test2 > test1
paulgear@localhost:~/tmp$ ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 paulgear paulgear   18 Jan 15 09:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 paulgear paulgear 3976 Jan 15 09:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 paulgear paulgear    0 Jan 15 09:29 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 paulgear paulgear    6 Jan 15 09:30 test1
```

Note how the complete replacement of the contents of test1 didn't update the directory time stamp.  So your find command probably should be looking for files as well as directories, something like this:

```
find . -mtime +180 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-w
```

Or you might want to make the time criteria different for files and directories:

```
find . -type d -mtime +120 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-w
find . -type f -mtime +180 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-w
```

For many (most?) applications using SMB file shares, this won't apply, because they usually write their contents to a temporary file in the same directory, then delete the original file, then rename the temporary file to the original's name.  But "database" applications like Access won't do this.